# ComponentArt Grid OnKeyPress Reset

Tags: c#, grid, onkeypress, componentart

Is there a way to reset the on key press search value and state through code (C#)?

The ComponentArt (CA) grid is being used to select a record from the database to update. I need to reset the search state when the update process is complete.

For some reason the on key press search/filter stays after re-binding the CA grid. I had to manually remove/delete the text from the search box to get access the whole records through the CA grid.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, I used **MyGrid.Search('');**, so I guess this may also be available in C# code.